# Get/Set Date and Time in C++

Tags: c++, date, time

for a project at uni i'm doing Home Automation, i need to be able to get date and time as well as setting both of them, i need this for automatic activations of certain functions, currently after seraching the web i have these for setting date and time

Date:

```
char date[9];
_strdate(date);
std::cout << date << std::endl;
```

Time:

```
time_t timer;
    struct tm y2k;
    double seconds;

    y2k.tm_hour = 0;   y2k.tm_min = 0; y2k.tm_sec = 0;
    y2k.tm_year = 100; y2k.tm_mon = 0; y2k.tm_mday = 1;

    time(&timer);  /* get current time; same as: timer = time(NULL)  */

    seconds = difftime(timer,mktime(&y2k));

    std::cout<<" seconds since January 1, 2000 in the current timezone" << seconds << std::endl;
```

What i want to know is is there a better way to do both of these, also how do i set the date and time?

Answer (score 1):

If you want your date/time code to be portable you might want to consider a library like the Boost [date/time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/date_time.html) library.

This will also give you the ability to do calculations and work with time intervals, etc. and you can concentrate on writing your own code instead of a library of custom date time methods and classes.

There are some contrived examples at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/date_time/examples/general_usage_examples.html

Answer (score 0):

Rather than declaring a struct, declare a class. That way, you can declare all of your data points within, and use getter and setter functions to modify and print them. Write it like this:

```
class y2k
{
    // Private variables
    int tm_hour;
    int tm_year;
    int tm_min;
    int tm_mon;
    int tm_sec;
    int tm_mday;
public:
    // Getters
    int getHour() {return tm_hour;}
    int getYear() {return tm_year;}
    int getMin() {return tm_min;}
    int getMon() {return tm_mon;}
    int getSec() {return tm_sec;}
    int getMDay() {return tm_mday;}

    // Setters
    void setHour(int hour) {hour = tm_hour;}
    void setYear(int year) {year = tm_year;}
    void setMin(int min) {min = tm_min;}
    void setMon(int mon) {mon = tm_mon;}
    void setSec(int sec) {sec = tm_sec;}
    void setMDay(int mday) {mday = tm_mday;}
};
```

Use the getters if you choose to print the value to the screen, and the setters if you want to set the data. For instance, if you declared `y2k foo`, then you could set the year like so: `foo.setYear(100)`.

Comment: That seems so simple now i see it in front of me, cheers man :)

Comment: what about the data types for the private variables, they all void?

Comment: @Tomsta I should've written it in my answer the first time, but they are all integers.

Comment: Thanks, just need to work out how to integrate this to my system, i think i have it set up as a subclass